# How can I determine ratios of products to create an end result?

Tags: algorithm, combinations

I have a number of objects with properties (length, width, height). I want to provide one or more constraints (eg. max width, min height) and have my program do a calculation of which objects and how many of each should be used to fit within the constraints.

How can I do this? Is there an algorithm?

Comment: You may want to post this on [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known as the Multidimensional Knapsack Problem and is NP-hard, which basically means, no, there aren't any nice algorithms that can solve your problem quickly. The Knapsack problem is a very popular research topic and there will be many academic papers detailing (often very complex) algorithms that provide good approximations, if you are interested in going that far.